# WPF Storyboard performance

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, rendering, storyboard

I've a storyboard in my project. And its changing render transform of a grid. When I played storyboard in Blend everything is okay animation playing smoothly but when I debug or publish my project and run it animation plays very poor and slowly. Performance is too low. What can I do for this problem? Thanks for all answers

Comment: Hard to answer without more specifics.  Can you include the XAML for your storyboard?